# Reduction formula for the tangent function squared

Tags: calculus

Find the reduction formula : $\tan^{2n}x dx, n ∋ ℤ+$

So I was thinking that I would break it into three parts then use integration by parts, but then there would be two terms with nth power still. If someone could show me how to do this that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\tan^{2n}x=\tan^{2n-2}x \tan^{2}x$

$\tan^{2}x=-1+\sec^{2}x$

You know the integral of second term.